What is the meaning of the expression "by the ears"?
I saw this expression : ((by the ears))  in the story that its name is the (unparalleled adventure of one hans pfaall)    : the full text is :By late accounts from Rotterdam, that city seems to be in a high state of philosophical excitement. Indeed, phenomena have there occurred of a nature so completely unexpected — so entirely novel — so utterly at variance with preconceived opinions — as to leave no doubt on my mind that long ere this all Europe is in an uproar, all physics in a ferment, all reason and astronomy together by the ears.

Is your doubt set by the ear or by the ear?  The title and the body text ask about different things.

Where did you see it? In your question there is no "set".

Needs a source for the phrase.  I suspect it is some quote from an old book and irrelevant to modern English.  It's certainly not an "idiom" I've ever heard/

The full quote for context:

By late accounts from Rotterdam, that city seems to be in a high state of philosophical excitement. Indeed, phenomena have there occurred of a nature so completely unexpected — so entirely novel — so utterly at variance with preconceived opinions — as to leave no doubt on my mind that long ere this all Europe is in an uproar, all physics in a ferment, all reason and astronomy together by the ears.
-"The Unparalleled Adventure of One Hans Pfaall" by Edgar Allan Poe

The Oxford English Dictionary includes an old English entry for "set by the ears," which is defined as causing people (or concepts) to fight or argue. Poe's expression that reason and astronomy was "together by the ears" suggests conflict or disorder. This also matches the troubled state of other items in his list which are "in uproar" and "in a ferment".

Thank you for your complete explanation .

The full quote from what source?

@Lambie Tomato source.

It's fine to have put it in with the edit, but it was not originally there. I do like Poe but don't know this one.

@Lambie I'd noticed you were Poe-faced.
